# How to make photographic film at home

Tags: film, diy

I am working on building my own camera. For the first part I made a simple lens design and crafted the lenses out of acrylic glass. My lens is a rough 100mm lens with 3 elements and I used a 3d printer to make a tube which holds those lenses together. The lens is mounted to a box which has an acrylic glass panel in the back where the image is projected on (I sanded the panel on the projection side and it works great!).

Now I would love to capture some sort of image on film but I want to make my own film. Please don't get me wrong - I know I cant make some "real" film- I am just looking for some solution to capture SOMETHING. Maybe I can paint a thin sheet of wood such that the image gets "burned" in after thirty minutes or so. I can remember that someone suggested me to use beetroot juice as a light sensitive paint but I prefer to ask before I'll try that.

The "film" then would be scanned and most likely converted to black and white. I'm just looking for a solution to be like "hey that was produced by me" and not "see how good my own camera performs". Do you have any hints? Also be aware that  I'm not into chemistry at all. I would prefer some household stuff over chemistry I would have to order.

Comment: This question is too broad because books have been written on the subject (eg, "The Book of Alternative Photographic Processes"). See [Alternative photographic processes A-Z](http://www.alternativephotography.com/processes/).

Comment: "Also be aware that im not into chemistry at all." – Perhaps making your own film is not something you should pursue. Why not just buy film?

Comment: Surprisingly, it *is* possible to make your own "film" -- on glass, a metal plate, or even on plastic film stock.  As noted, this is far beyond the scope of answers on this kind of site.  It's a lifetime study project.

Comment: "Film" _literally_ means, the plastic base. You can find books that talk about preparing your own light-sensitive coatings that can be applied to film, plates, or paper, but manufacturing your own plastic _film_ with good optical and mechanical qualities, may be more difficult and less rewarding than you expect.

Comment: If have seen the description of pinhole cameras that works with photographic  paper (of course, less sensitive than film), but in your case possibly easier to load.

Comment: Is this the type of thing you are asking about? https://fstoppers.com/portraits/step-step-guide-wet-plate-photography-2540

Answer (score 3):

Some years ago, there were a number of "liquid emulsion" products, which allowed you to "paint" a surface with sensitized gelatin similar to that on enlarging paper.  Once dried (in the dark) this could be exposed, either under an enlarger or in a camera, then developed much like a print to show an image (negative of the scene, though if on a black surface the image would become positive by reflection).

I don't know if these are still available, but such materials are within the scope of amateur production -- but how to actual do that job is far beyond what can be answered on this kind of site.  There was a photographer in Oregon ten years or so ago who had a very complete web site, documenting her methods, and made all her own plates and even sheet film.

Comment: https://www.freestylephoto.biz/liquid-emulsion   -  http://www.alternativephotography.com/the-liquid-emulsion-process/

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking into the same thing. With what I can find you can build a simple camera obscura and either use beetroot anthotypes in it to take a photo (bear in mind you may have to "take" the picture for several months) or you can use a chemigram solution to replicate photos the way they do with cyanotypes. The latter is much better of course, but you need a darkroom of some sort (no windows with a red lightbulb). The only downside with the latter is how easy it is to ruin the quality of the photo (this just means you may need to make a more advanced obscura). You can buy cyanotype solution on Amazon for like 8 dollars, in case you're lazy like me.

Sources:

- (Beet anthotype)
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=not-q659Diw
- (Camera obscura and cyanotype)
  https://makezine.com/projects/cardboard-cyanotype-camera/
- (Chemigrams)
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmFKLkuUNz0&t=677s

P.S.: I really hope this helps someone because I spent a lot of research on this topic because there seems to be no other information fit for this.

Answer (score 2):

Some woods, over days, lighten and darken after exposure to sun. I notice it on lumber deliveries, especially cedar.

I've been tempted to set a pinhole camera, with board as target of a scene, and wait.

Answer (score 1):

Off course you can make your own film (real one).
Start here: http://www.thelightfarm.com/

You can quite easily do ISO1 - ISO4 emulsion - while it wont be very fast it will give you a good quality picture.
Now just take some film and cover a tiny layer of emulsion on it (0.1mm or so)
roll and shoot.

Answer (score -1):

Google "film emulsion in a bottle".
Several brands are still available.